# Do we have support for parser generator with ANTLR version antlr-4.7.1?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

We have parser-generator code generated with version ANTLR v4.7.1. We wanted to add a new changes to the grammar and generate the code again with ANTLR v4.7.1.  We could not find the related version jar available to do the parsing. Could you please point me if we have any URLs to download the jar or migration notes from v4.7.1 to v4.10.1?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a terrible Question for Stack Overflow, and a waste of people’s time, since ANTLR has its own [dedicated web site](https://www.antlr.org/download.html) with a list of versions and release notes.

Comment: * https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tags * https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr4/ * https://github.com/antlr/website-antlr4/tree/gh-pages/download

Answer (score 1):

Maven hosts many versions.  Here’s the link   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr